# Passing function as a prop is not working (react)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, react-props

I am trying to call handleAddNote which is passed from App.js to AddNote.js but I am not able to reference it in AddNote without getting error saying handleAddNote is not a function. I have tried multiple ways but I always get it is not a function or is not defined. In the tutorial I'm following it says to simply call handleAddNote(noteText) in handleSave function but I am not able to.

```js
import Note from './Components/Note';
import NotesList from './Components/NotesList';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';


const App = () => {

  const[notes, setNotes] = useState([
    {
      id: nanoid(),
      text: "My first note",
      date: "2/12/2024"
    },
    {
      id: nanoid(),
      text: "My second note",
      date: "2/13/2024"
    },
    {
      id: nanoid(),
      text: "My third note",
      date: "2/14/2024"
    },
    {
      id: nanoid(),
      text: "My fourth note",
      date: "2/15/2024"
  }])

  const addNote = (text) => {
        console.log(text);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <NotesList notes={notes} handleAddNote={addNote}/>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import Note from './Note';
import AddNote from './AddNote';

const NotesList = ({ notes, handleAddNote }) => {
    return (
        <div className="notes-list">
            {notes.map((note)=> 
                <Note id={note.id} text={note.text} date={note.date}/>
            )}

            <AddNote handleAddNote={handleAddNote}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default NotesList;
```

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

const AddNote = ({ handleAddNote }) => {
    const [noteText, setNoteText] = useState("");

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setNoteText(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleSave = () => {
        console.log({handleAddNote});
        {handleAddNote(noteText)};
    };

    return(
        <div className="note new">
            <textarea 
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={noteText}
                className='new-note'
                rows="8" 
                columns="10" 
                placeholder="Type to add a note...">
            </textarea>

            <div className="note-footer">
                <small>200 remaining</small>
                <button className='save' onClick={(noteText)=>handleAddNote(noteText)}>Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}

export default AddNote
```

Comment: Where is note component?

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, it looks like the function is passed correctly to the child component.

Remove the curly braces `{handleAddNote(noteText)}` from `handleSave` function.

Just use `handleAddNote(noteText)`
and it should work.

Comment: I get the same error both ways unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how your project is laid out but made assumptions based on the import statements. We'll go file by file.

Before we start, the most important thing is *TO ALWAYS* have `import React from 'react';` at the top of your component files otherwise it'll lead to problems.

The directory structure I made looks like so:

- src

  - Components

    - AddNote.js
    - Note.js (not provided)
    - NotesList.js
  - App.js
  - index.js (runs App.js)

I do not know what is calling `App` so I created the file, `index.js` to handle that.

---

TLDR: Here is a demo - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/pseudo-class-sticker-sheet-forked-43k4pg

---

Let's start with:

### index.js

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

// Clear the existing HTML content
document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="app"></div>';

// Render your React component instead
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));
root.render(<App />);
```

Pretty self explanatory. Creates the div and renders the App component against it.

### App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import NotesList from "./Components/NotesList";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
const App = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([
    {
      id: nanoid(),
      text: "My first note",
      date: "2/12/2024",
    },
    {
      id: nanoid(),
      text: "My second note",
      date: "2/13/2024",
    },
    {
      id: nanoid(),
      text: "My third note",
      date: "2/14/2024",
    },
    {
      id: nanoid(),
      text: "My fourth note",
      date: "2/15/2024",
    },
  ]);

  const addNote = (text) => {
    const newNote = {
      id: nanoid(),
      text: text,
      date: new Date().toDateString(),
    };
    setNotes([...notes, newNote]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <NotesList notes={notes} handleAddNote={addNote} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I made no changes here outside of adding `setNotes` so the App renders.

### NotesList.js

```
import React from "react";
import Note from "./Note";
import AddNote from "./AddNote";

const NotesList = ({ notes, handleAddNote }) => {
  return (
    <div className="notes-list">
      {notes.map((note) => (
        <Note key={note.id} id={note.id} text={note.text} date={note.date} />
      ))}
      <AddNote handleAddNote={handleAddNote} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default NotesList;
```

Along with adding `import React from 'react'` I made sure to use `key` property so each element in the array is treated separately.

### AddNote.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const AddNote = ({ handleAddNote }) => {
  const [noteText, setNoteText] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setNoteText(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSave = () => {
    handleAddNote(noteText);
  };

  return (
    <div className="note new">
      <textarea
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={noteText}
        className="new-note"
        rows="8"
        columns="10"
        placeholder="Type to add a note..."
      ></textarea>

      <div className="note-footer">
        <small>200 remaining</small>
        <button className="save" onClick={handleSave}>
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddNote;
```

Most changes took place here. I changed the `onClick` so it points to the `handleSave` function. Originally, you had:
`onClick={(noteText)=>handleAddNote(noteText)}` which is incorrect since `nodeText` is actually a *MouseEvent* (`onClick = (e: MouseEvent)`).

Hope this clears things up and let me know if you have any issues/concerns.

Comment: Hello, I have tested using handleAddNote(noteText) and onClick={handleSave} but I am still getting the error. I'm very frustrated because it should work fine.

Comment: Mind pasting the error you're getting? The more info, the better